# How to upload a patched package to a Launchpad PPA

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages

I have a patch for gnome-terminal and already managed to create a PPA on launchpad. I also downloaded the source using apt-get source gnome-terminal.

Which steps do I have to do to create a .changes file for uploading to the PPA.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/